# Upsert using insert... on duplicate key update

Tags: php, mysql, upsert

There are many tutorials out there but i haven't been able to make it work somehow.

I am trying to update my table if data in all but except on column matches the data i'm inserting through a form. I am using php as the scripting language and mysql at the backend.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$genders = $_POST['gender'];
$hno = $_POST['hno'];
$sector = $_POST['sector'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$pin = $_POST['pin'];
$ailt = $_POST['ailt'];

$q="INSERT INTO manage (name, phone, gender, hno, sector, city, state, pin, ailt)
VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$genders', '$hno', '$sector','$city','$state','$pin','$ailt')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ailt='$ailt'";
```

What I'm trying to do is insert the data if it doesn't already exists, or if all the fields except `ailt` match, update that row with the new `ailt`.

I have been stuck on this for a couple of hours. Looks simple, but i just can't get it to work, as the rows keep inserting. They don't update, even when I keep all the data same and put a different value for ailt.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And exactly **HOW** is this not working? the insert fails? the on dupe doesn't work?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Can you post that?

Comment: its is a very strange query

Comment: The rows keep inserting. They don't update, even when i keep all the data same and put a different value for ailt.

Comment: @MarcB I'm aware this is vulnerable to sql injection. But this is just a small school project. I'll work on that aspect at a later moment.

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira Strange as in? I am a beginner, so any suggestions to improve upon the query are welcome.

Comment: If it's not updating, then nothing in your query is causing a unique key violation. e.g. your `ailt` field is not unique.

Comment: @user3508140 strange = when you use insert, its just for new registers, you need to use update to modify existing records. See the difference here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: you need set in your database your id colum with auto_increment too.

Comment: @MarcB Ahh right. So i need to set the combination of all the fields except  ailt unique, right? Because i need for every same entries of all the fields except ailt, it gets updated.

Comment: @user3508140 - See my updated answer. You'll want a UNIQUE/PRMARY key based on whatever fields uniquely identify an individual. In your case, a key covering "name" and "phone" may likely be enough, but you'll need to judge that based on your own use case.

Comment: I inserted the clarification from the comments into the question post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the comments are flooded with SQL injection, I won't hit on that again.

The syntax you're looking for is `UPDATE ailt=VALUES(ailt)`.

See the paragraph in [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) starting with "You can use the VALUES(col_name) function" for more detailed information.

Edit: Regarding your comment about how the rows "keep inserting", it's likely because you don't have a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key on the database that can identify what row to update. See the first paragraph of the docs I linked above for more reference.

Comment: It works now. Another thing. My id column(primary key and auto increment) increments by 2 everytime i update a row. For example my initial id was 1. When that row is updated, it remains 1. When i add another unique row, the id is now 3. Any workaround here, so it comes out be 2?

Comment: Not really. There are a multitude of reasons why an autoincrementing ID might not be perfectly sequential. For example, if you have records 5, 6, and 7, and delete 6, you'll still have record 5 and 7. Expecting them to be sequential is not worth the worry.

Comment: I needed the id's to be consecutive. I can manage that with PHP on the front-end.